# Zend Framework 2 onBootstrap redirection with dynamic variable in route

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a redirection in the onBootstrap function in the Module.php file which looks like:

```
$url = $e->getRouter()->assemble(array(), array('name' => 'administrator/error/acl')); // redirect to this URL
$response=$e->getResponse();
$response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', $url);
$response->setStatusCode(302);
$response->sendHeaders();

// stop further execution
$stopCallBack = function($event) use ($response){
    $event->stopPropagation();
    return $response;
};
$e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, $stopCallBack,-10000);

return $response;
```

While the route configuration looks like this (administrator is defined and works fine with other routes):

```
'error'=> array(
    'type'    => 'Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/error',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'MyAdmin\Controller\Error',
            'action' => 'index',
        ),
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes' => array(
        'error_name' => array(
            'type'    => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/[:error_name]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'error_name' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true
        ),
    ),
),
```

When it tries to redirect I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Route with name "acl" not found' in......

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `name` param should be the route name, in your case `error/error_name`. I'm not quite sure what 'administrator/error/acl' is in your example, if it's the `error_name` param that should appear in the URL, you want:

```
$url = $e->getRouter()->assemble(array(), array(
    'name' => 'error/error_name',
    'error_name' => 'administrator/error/acl'
));
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for your reply! The error_name parameter will determine which error message to display to the user. "acl" only means to show an error message saying that the user has no right to access the selected page. I have tried you solution but wasn't able to make it work. I have tried: $url = $e->getRouter()->assemble(array(), array('name' => 'administrator/error/error_name', 'error_name' => 'administrator/error/acl')); It redirects me to "/administrator/error/". The final parameter is removed automatically...